# React Native UseEffect API CALLS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, redux

How to handle multiple api calls in the same render ?

Example :

I want to get some info from first API call like this for example :

```
 const getUserInfo = async () => {
const response = await axios
  .get(`${API}/api/tenants/${app.tenant}/users/me`, axiosConfig)
  .then((r) => {
    return r.data;
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log("ERORR", e);
  });

return response;


 };

  const USER_INFO_SETTER = async () => {
    const fulldata = await getUserInfo();
    setUsername(fulldata.username);
    setDisplayname(fulldata.display_name);
    setId(fulldata.id);
    getAvatarId(fulldata.profile_image);
    setFirstName(fulldata.first_name);
    setLastName(fulldata.last_name);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    USER_INFO_SETTER();
  }, [isFocused]);
```

and i want to instantly use it for the next API CALL coming under this call

example :

```
const GET_ACTIVE_PROFILE_PICTURE = async () => {
try {
  const rez = await axios

    .get(`${API}/api/documents/document/${user.avatar_id}`, axiosConfig)
    .then((r) => {
      return r.config.url;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log("ERROR", e);
    });
  return rez;
} catch {
      console.log("error");
    }
  };

  const avatarSetted = async () => {
    const avatarLink = await GET_ACTIVE_PROFILE_PICTURE();
    setProfileImage(avatarLink);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    avatarSetted();
    console.log("123");
  }, []);
```

Soo the question is how to use information that i get inside first API call just after that in the api call below. because wihtout that information for example user.id_picture my second api call will return 500.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would create a couple of functions like so:

```js
const getUserInfo = () => {
  // This contains the axios request and returns the response.
};

const getActiveProfilePicture = () => {
  // This contains the axios request and returns the response.
};

const fetchUserInfo = () => {
  // This calls the getter and uses the response to update state.
};

const fetchActiveProfilePicture = () => {
  // This calls the getter and uses the response to update state.
};
```

I would also introduce 2 state variables, you may already have these so this step may be unnecessary.

```js
const [avatarId, setAvatarId] = useState(null);
const [profileImage, setProfileImage] = useState(null);
```

Fill out the logic for your functions you added above.

```js
const fetchUserInfo = useCallback(async () => {
  const response = await getUserInfo();
  
  // Perform all state updates.
  setAvatarId(response.profile_image);
}, []);

const fetchActiveProfilePicture = useCallback(async () => {
  const response = await getActiveProfilePicture();

  // Perform all state updates.
  setProfileImage(response);
}, []);
```

Next, create two `useEffects`:

- When the component mounts, call `fetchUserInfo`.
- When the `avatarId` has been retrieved and ultimately set in state, call `fetchActiveProfilePicture`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchUserInfo();
}, [fetchUserInfo]);

useEffect(() => {
  if(avatarId) {
    fetchActiveProfilePicture();
  }
}, [fetchActiveProfilePicture, name]);
```

You'll run into some warnings from eslint (`react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`) within this example about either wrapping functions in `useCallback` or placing the logic directly in `useEffect`. Just a heads up.

[Here's an example on CodeSandbox with the PokeAPI.](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-scott-8vg8c?file=/src/App.js)